# VueJS connecting to external data

Tags: javascript, json, rest, vue.js

I am learning VueJs. I have done a simple project you can see here:

```js
var vuePosts = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-posts',
  data: {
    posts: [
      {title: 'title 1', body: 'message 1'},
      {title: 'title 2', body: 'message 2'}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div class="vue-test" id="vue-posts">
  <h1>Vue Test</h1>
  <ul v-for="post in posts">
    <li>
      <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{post.body}}</p>
      <hr />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see I am just doing a v-for and taking the post for the js file.

My question is how should I do it I want to use the data from an external source like

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

How can I import the data to my `data:` and name it as posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method, which will make a call to the remote API, get the data and assign it to your data variable `this.posts`. Code inspired from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882134/does-vue-js-work-with-ajax-http-calls), will look like following:

```
  methods: {
    getPosts: function() {
      var that = this
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        method: 'GET'
      }).then(function (response) {
        if(response.error) {
          console.err("There was an error " + response.error);
        } else {
          console.log(response.posts);
          this.posts = response.posts
        }
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
    }
  }
```

and you can call this methods from mounted block, which will fetch and assign the posts when your component is mounted.

```
mounted () {
  this.getPosts()
}
```

You can also have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41165328/1610034) on how to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) which is a HTTP client for making api calls

See working pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJwWQR).

Comment: Before anything thanks for your time saurabh. I have tried to add this bit of code you have given me but I haven't been able to make it work. Please see my codepen http://codepen.io/fparedlo/pen/LxEqGX

Comment: @noway I have made minor changes in your pen, check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJwWQR).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I am keeping your code and study it.