# vue js trigger other component method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

my files looks like this

```
./components/UserCreate.vue
./components/UserList.vue
./main.js
```

my vue instance in main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#user-operations',
  components: {
      CreateUser,
      UserList
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<div id="user-operations">
  <create-user></create-user>
  <user-list></user-list>
</div
```

I want to trigger **userList()** method in **UserList.vue** when **createUser()** method in **CreateUser.vue** is triggered. Or how can i pass last_user property to **UserList component** from **CreateUser.vue** for append.

here is my create-user component [working]

https://jsfiddle.net/epp9y6vs/

here is my user-list component [working]

https://jsfiddle.net/ore3unws/

so i want the last user to be listed when createUser() is triggered

Comment: Please provide the code including the call  of userCreate() method. If you can provide an example on jsfiddle with the problem you described - it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: I am sorry.. added

Comment: Use emit from userList, and listen to emitted custom event on userOperations. From there you can trigger a method in its child component createUser.

Comment: can you give me a small sample please

Comment: Please edit your original question or comment it, instead of asking again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386817/how-can-i-access-another-vue-instance-from-a-vue-component

Comment: actually the old code is structurally different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to create a service with all the methods operating user entities. It will separate your Components from the implementaton of the logic which is good because:

1. The Components doesn't have to know which calls they have to do to servers to retrieve data - it's better to use abstraction level
2. The Component will be lighter and easier for reuse
3. You will be able to use this logic (from the service) in several Components - exactly your problem

You have several ways to implement services:

1. Stateless service: then you should use mixins
2. Statefull service: use Vuex
3. Export service and import from a vue code
4. any javascript global object

I prefer (4). Here is an example how to do it:

In file `/services/UsersService` that will describe your service put all the relevant methods and expose them with export:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  get() {
    return axios.get('/api/posts)
  }
}
```

Then in any Component that needs this methods import this service:

```
import UsersService from '../services/UsersService'

export default {
  data() {
   return {
     items: []
   }
  },
  created() {
   this.fetchUsers()
  },
  methods: {
   fetchUsers() {
    return UsersService.get()
      .then(response => {
        this.items = response.data
      })
   }
  }
}
```

Find even more about it in this question:
[What's the equivalent of Angular Service in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164672/whats-the-equivalent-of-angular-service-in-vuejs)

This solution is much better than using `this.$parent.$refs.userList` which suppose that this components will always stay "brothers" (will have the same parent).

Comment: now I have one Vue Instance. I imported userList and userCreate to userOperation Component. And hooked userOperation component to Vue Instance in main.js. thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can trigger `userList` in `CreateUser.vue` by this code:

   `this.$parent.$refs.userList.userList()`

and change your `index.html`:

```
<div id="user-operations">
  <create-user></create-user>
  <user-list :ref="userList"></user-list>
</div>
```

2. You can create `last_user` property in `main.js` then pass it to 2 components:

.

```
<div id="user-operations">
  <create-user:lastUser="last_user"></create-user>
  <user-list :lastUser="last_user"></user-list>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried the first one and I first got this error for that <b>:ref="userList"</b> 

>Property or method "getUsers" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option  

and i changed just <b>ref="userList"</b> and this time when i create a new user i get this error

>Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUsers' of undefined at VueComponent.<anonymous> [this one -->this.$parent.$refs.UserList.userList();]

Comment: It should be `<b :ref="userList"></b>`. `ref` is 1 property of this element. And `this.$parent.$refs.userList.userList()` not `this.$parent.$refs.UserList.userList()`, please carefully check your code