# Vuejs Is this a good way of implementing services?

Tags: vue.js, model-view-controller, service

i recently learned the mvc architecture and worked with angular and now i am working with vuejs and i tried to make models and services more like angular is this a good way, is there a better way ? this is the service

```
//service for company
import axios from 'axios';
export default{   

    getCompany(id){

        console.log('using function getCompany');

        return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/company/'+id);
    },
}
```

now the model

```
//model for company
export class CompanyModel{
    name;
    location;
    salary;
    constructor(data){
        this.name = data.name;
        this.location = data.location;
        this.salary = data.salary;
        console.log('CompanyModel constructor is used!');

    }
}
```

and this is how i use them in the component to show the company

```
data() {
    return{
       companyModel:{},
    }
},

mounted() {
    CompanyService.getCompany(2)
    .then((response) =>{
        this.companyModel = new CompanyModel(response.data);
    });

},
```

Problem: i need to know if this is good enough, or is there a more natural way with vuejs and I don't like how i need to complete the axios request from the service, i wanted to extract all the request in the service i couldn't.. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, if you do not want to store data directly in a component, you use a vuex store. Have you looked into Vuex before? You would abstract the api call to a module action, the `CompanyModel` would be data within the module. The component maps a computed property to a module getter or state.

Comment: I haven't checked it yet, but thanks i will, however it's not i don't want to store data directly it's the part i use then((response) =>{}) in the component, but i want to implement that part in the service, but i haven't been able to, let's say i have been i able to accomplish that, do you think if use vuex store it would be better? from a design point of vue.

Comment: I use services to separate concerns and make testing easier. This question [What's the equivalent of Angular Service in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164672/whats-the-equivalent-of-angular-service-in-vuejs) defines options concisely. As for 'completing the axios request', not sure what the problem is - a Promise is a valid return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a good first version here: [What's the equivalent of Angular Service in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164672/whats-the-equivalent-of-angular-service-in-vuejs/54165192#54165192)

You can then couple that with your `services` to avoid calling axios all the time.

Comment: Aha Thanks, it's almost the same philosophy i wanted to use, just one more thing, i already checked vuex, it does a good job making services, the reason i wanted to work the same way as angular is i may need to reuse something, but vuex as i can see is more natural to vue haha so i think one cannnot have everything