# Does Vue 3 support something like Angular-Services?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, porting

I'm porting a project from AngularJs to Vue3. In Angular we have a service component, which creates und supplies objects to components. The objects are automatically reactive, if they are used in a binding in a component. If component A changes an object, the View of component B shows the change of the state immediately.

[image: Components and objects in AngularJs]

Is there a way to accomplish such a service in Vue3? The goal is, to maintain an array of objects, and every change to the array is reflected in the Views of the different components.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41164672/17447

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a 'store' ? Like vue pinia. Pinia is a more flexible way than vuex. It keeps data centralized no matter from what components it is mutating and getting. (if written correctly)

Comment: Vue doesn't specifically have such entity. This is the role that composable functions usually play. They are reactive because of composition api. For global services (singletons) composition api is just directly used in a module, so it's evaluated once and shared between comps. As it was just said, pinia stores can play this role too. There can be multiple stores and they can be instantiated per comp and reflect local state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the records: This is, what I came up with, as simple sample code. First I wrote a little service:

```
import { reactive } from "vue";
export const objectService = {
    objects: reactive([]), // reactive is important, otherwise it doesn't work
    start: function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            ((j)=>{
                setTimeout(()=> // I use setTimeout as example for an async operation
                    objectService.objects.push({value: j}), 1000);
            })(i);
    }
};
```

The point here is, that the service manipulates the state in an async operation (in real live systems a rest call or access to indexedDb, etc).

Now there are two components running in two separate Vue apps. The reason, why they run in separate apps is out of the scope of the issue here. App1:

```
<template>
<!--App1.vue-->
<p>Here is App1</p>
<div v-for="obj,ix in objectService.objects" :key="ix">{{obj.value}}
    <input v-model="obj.value" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { objectService } from '../services/object-service.js';

const App1 = defineComponent({
    setup() {
        return { objectService };
    },
})

export default App1;
</script>
```

App2:

```
<template>
<!--App2.vue-->
<p>Here is App2</p>
<div v-for="obj,ix in objectService.objects" :key="ix">{{obj.value}}
    <input v-model="obj.value" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { objectService } from '../services/object-service.js';

const App2 = defineComponent({
    setup() {
        // const os = objectService;
        objectService.start();
        return { objectService };
    },
})

export default App2;
</script>
```

These 2 components are identical with one exception: App2 calls the start method of the service. The result is shown in both components. And each of the components can alter the state, which is immediately reflected in the other component.

The point of the whole solution is the use of reactive({}) in the service. I hope, this is useful for somebody.

Again thanks to Estus Flask & hc_dev to point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

### Differences: Vue VS AngularJS

Vue is a UI framework that doesn't specifically have such entities as *services*, it is up to a developer to implement them. Also in contrast to Angular, Vue doesn't provide *dependency-injection* (DI) features.

#### Composables as service in Vue

In Vue, reusable component code is supposed to be provided by [**composables**](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) or *composable functions*, their reactivity is implemented with composition API:

```
// Usage: service = useLocalService()
const useLocalService = () => {
  const someState = reactive({});
  const someAction = () => /* change state */;
  return { someState, someAction }
};
```

#### provide / inject to share services in Vue (compare DI)

For *global singleton services* that are inherent in Angular, service state is defined in a module and evaluated once, so it's shared across the app:

```
// Usage: import * as service from '...';
export const someGlobalState = reactive({});
export const someGlobalAction = () => /* change state */;
```

Whether it's beneficial to wrap it in a composable function for consistency depends on a situation:

```
// Usage: service = useGlobalService()
const someGlobalState = reactive({});
const someGlobalAction = () => /* change state */;

const useGlobalService = () => {
  return { someGlobalState, someGlobalAction }
};
```

In Angular 2 or later, DI containers allow to provide service instances per component hierarchy. In Vue, this is done through [`provide`/`inject`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html):

```
// Usage in a parent: setupRootOrNestedService()
const setupRootOrNestedService = () => {
  const someRootOrNestedState = reactive({});
  const someRootOrNestedAction = () => /* change state */;
  
  provide('rootOrNestedService', { someRootOrNestedState, someRootOrNestedState });
};

// Usage in a child: service = useRootOrNestedService()
const useRootOrNestedService = () => {
  return inject('rootOrNestedService');
};
```

This allows to identify services by tokens at any level and benefit from using DI pattern.

#### Pinia

[`Pinia`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) (a Vue store) library provides lightweight state management influenced by [*Flux pattern*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/295119/understanding-flux-pattern). It relies on composition API and allows for multiple stores. The result is similar to the above, with the addition of a convention over code, extended Vue devtools, proper TypeScript typing, and a plugin layer:

```
// Usage as local service: service = useLocalOrGlobalService()
// Usage as global service: export default useLocalOrGlobalService()
// And: import * as service from '...';
const useLocalOrGlobalService = () => {
  return defineStore('localOrGlobalService' + random(), {
    state: () => ({}),
    actions: {
      someAction() { /* change state */ }
    }
  })
};
```

Pinia doesn't restrict ways in which a store is instantiated and provided to components, so it can be combined with `provide`/`inject` if necessary.