# Pinia store vs composable functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, function-composition

I would like to figure out what are the advantages of using Pinia store instead of using just pure ts composable functions like

```
const userName = ref('')

export default function useUser() {

  const setUserName(name: string) => {
    userName.value = name
  }

  return {
    userName: readonly(userName),
    setUserName
  }

}
```

and then usage

```
const {userName, setUserName} = useUser()
```

Because, for example here in this Vitesse example https://github.com/antfu/vitesse/blob/main/src/stores/user.ts, the Pinia usage looks very similar.

Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: See the post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570033/does-vue-3-support-something-like-angular-services/72573875#72573875 , I suppose it sums up the benefits of the use of Pinia in comparison with vanilla composition

Comment: The different in your example is that everytime you call your composable, it will create a new user. While with pinia it is shared across the whole app, no matter how many times you use your store.

Comment: oh my bad. the user ref should be out of the functio. I've updated the example

Answer (score 16):

I found this explanation, and it makes sense to me:

> I feel like you may be missing the point of Composables and the Composition API a bit - they are useful as a way of organising your code "feature-first", rather than "component-first" (literally, throught composition). This means that Composables are shared functionality, not state.

> Certain functionalities may include internal (shared, app-wide) state, but that isn't the purpose of Composables per se. Pinia, on the other hand, is meant for sharing state exclusively. It may include functionality to manage said state, but it doesn't exist without that shared state.

> A good place to see this "in action" is Vue Use, a set of common-use composables. Some may include internal state, but most do not, so that only augment a component's functionality, perhaps adding some local state (as opposed to global, shared state)

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/t88xzy/comment/hzmoet2/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Ok I understand the point that the composable functions are typically without state or "should be" without state but why? Is there any technical reason why it is not recommended to use them even with a state? Usually I've been using compositions only, with shared states and in order to keep reactivity and single responsibility in other composable functions I've set `watch`er to be notified when some state has changed

Comment: When I see the Pinia example from Vitesse template, it is almost the same approach as I am using compositions with a state, but the only difference is it is registered as `defineStore()`  so I will be using it, since there is a small benefit to see it in the Vue Devtools ;)

Answer (score 11):

I'm currently struggling with this choice too at the beginning of a middle-sized project. I think Pinia is actually **inferior** to plain composables as Pinia creates problems without apparent reason and doesn't give anything in return.

1. Pinia breaks object destructure which is super convenient:

   ```
   const {userName} = useUserStore(); // broken! reactivity lost
   ```

   vs

   ```js
   const {userName} = useUser(); // userName is normal ref
   ```

   There is `storeToRefs`, but it's a stupid ritual and it's double stupid as you have to use refs from `storeToRefs`, but methods from original store:

   ```
   const store = useUserStore();
   const {userName, setUserName} = storeToRefs(store); // setUserName is broken!
   ```

   It's also quite strange API when you return a ref from your store definition, but then it becomes a non-ref field of a reactive object.
2. Pinia has false promises - declared devtools support is actually rudimentary. There are no timeline nor timetravel in official devtools with official plugin. You only get your stores in a separate devtool tab, but you can still get to the state of your composables without Pinia.
3. As a result of breaking the refs, Pinia promotes a style where you hide reactivity under the rag instead of clearly identifying what is a ref and what is not, multiplying mistakes.

Comment: I actually concur with this. Pinia I think can be useful for large stores, but if you are working on a small to mid sized app, I think using simple composables with global refs to manage your state is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Pinia for its benefits, but want to be able to destructure refs from the store directly without using `storeToRefs` everywhere, consider exposing an additional wrapper composable like so:

```js
const useSessionStore = defineStore('session', () => {
  const user = ref(undefined)
  const setUser = value => user.value = unref(value)
  return {
    user,
    setUser,
  }
}

const useSession = () => {
  const store = useSessionStore()
  const refs = storeToRefs(store)
  return {
    ...store,
    ...refs
  }
}

//Use:
const {user, setUser} = useSession()
user.value //Reactive!
setUser('bob') //Works!
```

This way, you can use the `useSession` composable when you just need the refs directly, and still use `useSessionStore` if you want access to the full reactive store object.